# TypeScript compiler equality narrowing is incorrect after non-local mutation

Tags: typescript, type-inference, narrowing

The TypeScript compiler can perform [equality narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#equality-narrowing) to infer that a value has a specific literal type. However, that inference may last longer than is actually valid. In the example below, the compiler thinks that `this.state` must have the literal type `"ALIVE"` longer than it actually does.

```js
class GameData {
    state: string = "ALIVE";

    maybeUpdateState() {
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            this.state = "DEAD";
        }
    }

    doTick() {
        if (this.state == "ALIVE") {
            console.log("Game is alive");
            this.maybeUpdateState();
            if (this.state == "DEAD") { // <-- Compiler error here!
                console.log("Game died");
            }
        }
    }
}

new GameData().doTick();
```

This results in the following (incorrect) compiler error:

> **This condition will always return 'false' since the types '"ALIVE"' and '"DEAD"' have no overlap.**

[(Playground link)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDiYFsCmARMAXM0DeBYAUNEdBJukgFwnoBOAlgHYDm0AvNAEQCCAMgJIA1AKIcA3AQLFoCMAE8ARkgCqABwAmGJAGUySABQBKHJKnE6AM2h6AshgAWAOhpgGagPYJD0ADzQADA4ArEZ4hKbh6HZ0EA6kmmycKEJcKGIm4QC+6dBZ+NnuACp0wADWXqHhRBZWkdGxumzs3PzCHCHZldDAbgwQbiBIDiBuTHoc8MjQ0dBgIHQAbkht4mGdRLUxMgrK6po6moYra2aWehv18axNSSltONAA9A8+ALQv0ADCHip0AzTQSBoNDc-zsgKQAEIOscuj0+gMhiMxhMkNA1HQkGpltDMjictlcrkCAwkAB3OCIVAYMCGByFYplAyiIA)

This is obviously not true. I've figured out that there are ways I could work around this at the line where I do the second equality test -- for instance, I could rewrite it as `if (this.state as string == "DEAD")`.

But instead of potentially having to do that every place I want to do an equality test against that property, **is there any way that I can update `maybeUpdateState()`** to let the compiler know that it mutates the object such that inferences about the object's properties may no longer be valid after it is called?

I haven't been able to find any other discussion about this specific issue in my online searching, so references to other Q&As/issues/posts would also be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like this TypeScript issue is probably relevant, though it's pretty broad and has a long discussion history: [Trade-offs in Control Flow Analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-235963457)

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it:

```js
if (this.state.includes("DEAD")) {}
```

Now, if you wanna make this mutation a bit more predictable use a type:

```js
type GameState = "ALIVE" | "DEAD";

state: GameState = "ALIVE";
```

So even if you fudge up the codes and typo `this.state = "DEAAD"`, for example, the compiler then flunks the build which is desirable.